# I am having problem in installing solana tool in my PC. ( windows 10 )

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, installation

So, when i was using this following code while installing :
C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe v1.16.14

Then I got the error showing "Your system cannot execute this program" or something.

Can you please help me to fix this.

Comment: Please share the detailed logs here.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be caused by any of the following reasons:

- 1. Lack of Permission: Please open your terminal as an administrator before running the command.
- 2. Insufficient hardware resources: Ensure you have the right hardware resources to install the CLI.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.solana.com/getstarted/local#install-the-solana-cli)

Also, please take note of your operating system when following the docs.